# Multi platform docker compose issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm facing a weird issue when I try to run my docker compose file. It currently consists of one .net api in windows and one database in linux. Until now I had no problems running it with using Windows containers on Docker desktop. Randomly now, I can to run it with the error:

*Error response from daemon: pull access denied for database, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied*

My database image is on my local machine, tried also the docker login option but the issue persists. Not sure if it helps also but on Docker Desktop I can see either Windows or Linux containers. Any ideas what is causing that?

Docker compose:

```
services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: database
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD= (password I use)
  api:
    image: api
    container_name: api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
    ports:
      - "9902:80"
    links:
      - "database"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `build` entry to let compose know you are dealing with a local image:

```yaml
services:
  database:
    image: database
    build: .
    ...
```

Then run `docker compose up --build`. If the `database` image is built from a different folder than where the `docker-compose.yml` is located, you'll need to alter the `build` path to something other than `.` e.g. `./database`.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but even though experimental option is true while running windows containers I can't still see both windows and linux images when I run docker images -a . On another computer that I use I have no problem running it